# Обработка REST-запросов на сервере (Java)

Tags: java, сервер

Каким простым способом, без огромных фреймворков, относительно легковесно, можно поднять сервер на Java?

Comment: _"Адрес вида IP:PORT я, скорее всего, смогу указать"_. К сожалению, не сможете: ВК не позволяет указывать порт в адресе callback'а.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для простого старта могу предложить эти библиотеки:

- http://sparkjava.com/

Это маленький фреймворк для запуска веб сервера "из коробки". Если устроят настройки по умолчанию, достаточно будет указать только методы обработки запросов.

[Вот тут есть пример RestAPI приложения.](https://sparktutorials.github.io/2015/04/03/spark-lombok-jackson-reduce-boilerplate.html)

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        get("/hello", (req, res) -> {
            return "Hello World";
        });
    }
}
```

- https://github.com/google/gson

Эта библиотека которую указывают в примерах предыдущего фреймворка и, пожалуй лучше ее и использовать.

```
// Serialization
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson(1);            // ==> 1
gson.toJson("abcd");       // ==> "abcd"
gson.toJson(new Long(10)); // ==> 10
int[] values = { 1 };
gson.toJson(values);       // ==> [1]

// Deserialization
int one = gson.fromJson("1", int.class);
Integer one = gson.fromJson("1", Integer.class);
Long one = gson.fromJson("1", Long.class);
Boolean false = gson.fromJson("false", Boolean.class);
String str = gson.fromJson("\"abc\"", String.class);
String[] anotherStr = gson.fromJson("[\"abc\"]", String[].class);
```

Comment: 1) Главная цель этого языка - по максимуму скрыть различия между платформами. Поэтому это должно меньше всего вас беспокоить. 2) Если мне не изменяет память, для веба по умолчанию используется порт 80. Или же надо узнать на какой порт обращается VK и указать его. (Spark.port(8080);)

Comment: Это не рнр, тут папки не затрагиваются. В примере, что у меня указан, первым параметром идет именно внутренний адрес сайта (то что идет после localhost:80), там можно указать как произвольный, так и корневой "/". Добавил в ответ ссылку на пример с RestAPI приложением на спарке.